# Media file path based vulnerablity

Tags: configuration, media-library

During a vulnerability scan, Path-Based Vulnerability has been reported in the below-mentioned links,

www.sample.com/web/abcdefgh/ijklmnop/-/document_library_display.old
www.sample.com/web/abcdefgh/ijklmnop/-/document_library_display.bak
www.sample.com/web/abcdefgh/ijklmnop/-/document_library_display.inc

We do not find any .old, .bak and .inc files present anywhere in the application.how to avoid accessing these extensions.

Comment: Do you mean something like http://www.cognifide.com/our-blogs/sitecore/sitecore-serves-media-items-even-with-incorrect-extensions/ ? Please keep in mind that I wrote this blog post 6 years ago so you may need to tweak it a bit.

Comment: I tried this but can't able to load images or videos in any format.it works when i mention request.mediaextension is ashx .but am having jpg its not working

Comment: I think you need to provide more details of what the scan was testing exactly. I could understand if the scan was for a `/-/meida/` based URL but the sample URLs you have provided should not trigger for media and should throw 404 for items in the tree (using OOTB settings at least)

Comment: http://sitename/-/media/452EDF85EC134B6DBB3854C611B25E81.old
http://sitename/-/media/BD7B7D26BBF84EE1BA1AD49143392250.ashx~
http://sitename/-/media/A98C060B95224837BF42DA3F8CFB75A9.bak
http://sitename/-/media/BD7B7D26BBF84EE1BA1AD49143392250.ashx~
http://sitename/-/media/A98C060B95224837BF42DA3F8CFB75A9.bak
http://sitename/-/media/A35286824E2C4EF1978B275B1AC3BBAD.orig
http://sitename/-/media/837FDEF9E11D4F468071004B3738F679.inc
http://sitename/-/media/66B7AF805E484025B54ED7C820539613.ashx~

Comment: Need to avoid acessing media file with invalid extensions

Answer (score 4):

It's a known issue that Sitecore will serve media requests regardless of the request extension. If you want to prevent media being accessed using an incorrect extension then you need to handle this yourself.

### Media Request Event

One option is to add an handler for the `media:request` event that will check the file extension of the request against the resolved media item, and return a 404 status code if they do not match.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using Sitecore.Events;
using Sitecore.IO;
using Sitecore.Resources.Media;

namespace MySite.Custom.Media.Events
{
    public class CheckMediaExtension
    {
        public void OnMediaRequest(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            // Safety checks
            if (Sitecore.Context.Site.Name.Equals(Sitecore.Constants.ShellSiteName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                return;
            var sitecoreEventArgs = (SitecoreEventArgs) args;
            if (sitecoreEventArgs == null || !sitecoreEventArgs.Parameters.Any())
                return;
            var request = (MediaRequest) sitecoreEventArgs.Parameters[0];
            if (request == null)
                return;

            // Now we've established we have a valid request
            var mediaItem = MediaManager.GetMedia(request.MediaUri).MediaData.MediaItem;
            string requestExtension = FileUtil.GetExtension(request.InnerRequest.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.FilePath);

            if (!string.Equals(mediaItem.Extension, requestExtension, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                var response = request.InnerRequest.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response;
                response.Clear();
                response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
                response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
                response.End();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then patch this event handler in:

```xml
<sitecore>
  <events>
    <event name="media:request">
      <handler type="MySite.Custom.Media.Events.MediaRequestEvent, MySite.Custom" method="OnMediaRequest"/>
    </event>
  </events>
</sitecore>
```

If you go down this route then make sure you have set the `Media.RequestExtension` to empty, which will cause the media URLs to be generated with the correct file type extension.

```xml
<!--
  MEDIA - REQUEST EXTENSION
  The extension to use in media request URLs.
  If the value is not set, the Extension field of the individual media items 
  will be used (ie. JPG, GIF, etc.)
  Default value: "ashx"
-->
<setting name="Media.RequestExtension" set:value=""/>
```